# Canonical isomorphism from Ext to $H^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

In [this text](http://staff.math.su.se/shapiro/ProblemSolving/GasbarriABC.pdf) on page 15, remark 3.17 they note (for a projective variety $X_F$ over $F$, $F$ being a function field over $k$) that

$$\operatorname{Ext}^1(\Omega_{X_F/F}^1; \mathcal{O}_{X_F})$$
is canonically isomorphic to [the $F$ finite dimensional vector space]
$$H^1(X_F; f^*(\Omega_{F/k}^1) \otimes (\Omega_{X/F}^1)^{\vee}).$$

Unfortunately, I have no idea why. Could anyone point me to the right lemma's in some book (probably Hartshorne) or show me why this follows?

EDIT: I also question if this was really the remark he wanted to make, because a few lines above this he is looking at $$\operatorname{Ext}^1(\Omega_{X_F/F}^1; f^*(\Omega_{F/k}^1))$$ which makes more sense to me.

Comment: What is $f$ here? For any two vector bundles $E,G$, $\mathrm{Ext}^1(F,G)=H^1(F^{\vee}\otimes G)$.

Comment: $X_F$ is defined by $f: X_F \to \operatorname{Spec}(F)$